# javascript text replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

i am using [jquery replaceText plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/). with this plugin i can successfully replace text of an element like this:

```
<div>some text to be replaced here.</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("div").replaceText("some text to be replaced here", "a new text for replacement");
})
</script>
```

however when that div becomes something like this:

```
<div>some text to be <a href="somelink">replaced</a> here.</div>
```

the replacement is not working.

how should i proceed here?

Comment: What should the result be in the second case?

Comment: Well what do you want to happen in that situation? E,g. should the `<a>` element just disappear leaving the `<div>` with just the new text as plain text?

Comment: @FelixKling @nnnnnn i would like the `<a>` element to stay as otherwise is breaking the page. however i also would like to know how it would be if it just disappeared.

Comment: OK, so you want to keep the `<a>`, but what will be its content after the replace operation? How would you decide which word(s) from the replacement text end up inside the `<a>` and which end up outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to replace a subset of text with another subset of text and you want to work across nodes.

Looks like you want a [Range](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-range).

So you just have to make a new `Range` using `document.createRange()`. Make it point to where you content starts.

So just find the start node and the start offset somehow then call `range.setStart(node, offset)`. I would presume the `node` will be your container and the offset is just calculated.

Then call `range.extractContents()` to remove the original text from the DOM.

Then just `range.insertNode(textNode)` to insert the next text into the DOM.

Comment: this is actually the closest to what I want. however instead of replacing the text, I have decided on replacing the html which is better. now all I need to know is how to get the selected text's html properly.

Answer (score 1):

When operating on the HTML of the page, all the tags are in the HTML stream so you can't just do a direct replacement of only the text without allowing for intervening tags.

It isn't matching `"some text to be replaced here"` because that string of text doesn't exist as a single string of text in this HTML:

```
div>some text to be <a href="somelink">replaced</a> here.</div>
```

You would have to replace individual pieces of text that actually exist as individual streams of text like `"some text to be "` and `"replaced"`.